# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined"

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component, vuex, laravel-mix

I am rendering a custom component list (this is just an example) as below:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li
                v-for="(item, index) in componentList"

                :field-name="MyFieldName"
         >
               <custom_component :index="index" 
                   :some-prop="item.someProps" />
        ></li>
    </ul> 
</template>

<script> 


 export default { 
   name: 'myListComp';

   props: {

     },
     ... other props
  },

  data () {
   return {
        /// ... some other variable/properties for this instance
        myFieldName: '',
       componentList: []
    }
   },

  created () {
        // ...
       Load data from props
       this.myFieldName = this.fieldName;
       // Initialize Component List with the data
       this.componentList = this.initializeComponentList();
         // ...
    },

    methods:{
      initializeComponentList() { 
        // Get the list from AJAX
        return [{}, {}, ....];
      }
    }

} 
</script>
```

I am getting some weird error as below while rendering the component list.

On a side note ... I am using the latest laravel-mix ^2.1.11 for compiling the vue components. I am using Vue ^2.5.16 and vuex ^3.0.1.
 [image]

Comment: I figured out the problem is because of the unique key requirement of vueJS when we render components using v-for loop. I have simply added a new function to create the unique Index and it has solved my problem.

Comment: please, show how you use a component `<CustomComponentList>`

Comment: I solved it by passing the unique key in the rendered list.